# How to make Access Database data source path dynamic for Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, ms-access, crystal-reports

I have developed a Windows Form App using **C#** & **Microsoft Access Database (.accdb)**. I have created a Crystal Report. In Crystal Report there is an option called **"Database Expert"**. Using **"Database Expert"** option I have attached my Access database file with Crystal Report using **OLE DB (ADO)** like below picture:

[image: datasource]

Now I have created another form and bind a Crystal Report Viewer with this form. I have coded these code on Form Load Event:

```cs
private void BillingInvoiceForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int BillPrint = Billing_Form.BillNoToPrint;
    ReportDocument crypt = new ReportDocument();
    crypt.Load(@"Report\BillingReport.rpt");
    crypt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{Bill_Master.Bill_No} =  " + BillPrint + "";
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crypt;
    crystalReportViewer1.Show();
}
```

As you can see there is a path like "F:\Visual Studio Projects\BillingSystem\db\My_Database.accdb"

When I run this app into my machine, everything works fine but when I deploy this app into another machine it gets stuck. Because app can not find path like "F:\Visual Studio Projects\BillingSystem\db\My_Database.accdb".

So my question is that how can I make Crystal Report data source path dynamic so that this app can be run on every computer.

Comment: Assuming this is a new project, I would seriously consider if access is appropriate. In my experience it is neither particularly stable,  nor scalable. And for most use cases there should be better alternatives available.

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately I have to use only Access database only for this small project. Please help me to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Also let me know, how did you put my image correctly? Even when I upload it, it only showed a link.

Comment: You either need to deploy the database with your application and use a relative path (if you can find a way to edit the path by hand). Or put the file on a network drive, but this will likely fail horribly since access does not handle multiple concurrent users well, if at all. But I'm not really familiar enough with the libraries to provide specific recommendations.

Comment: I have successfully added relative path and it is working on any machine correctly. I am getting only problem with Crystal Report Data Source. How is it possible to have dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to switch to ODBC as the data source. That way, the same ODBC DSN on different machines can point at different physical locations.

It is possible to change the data source in code but that requires more advanced knowledge of the Crystal runtime and comes with other challenges as well. There are 3rd-party Crystal Reports viewers that handle that challenge but I would advise you to go with the simpler solution of using ODBC.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. Can you please explain ODBC DSN in details so that I & others can get benefit of it. Also explain it how can we use it using Access database for making Crystal Report Data Source dynamic for every machine.